# Which better way to change array of object's value by another array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

I have

```
var a = ["4", "2"],
b = [{"item": "1"}, {"item": "4"}, {"item": "2"}, {"item": "3"}];
```

now i need to find each a's value with b's value when if i found matched value then need to create

```
c=[{"item": false}, {"item": true}, {"item": true}, {"item": false}]
```

I have jsfiddle with above 
[example](https://jsfiddle.net/kvijayanand/28qck4av/5/) here but array order is changed. the out come should be like above "c" array and also need to reduce number of filter method and map.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your attempt here on Stack Overflow. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to do so.

Comment: `b.map(x => ({item: a.includes(x.item)}))` - this?

Comment: @georg beat me too it! ;)

Comment: Will IE supports "includes" method?

Comment: no, it does not support `includes`, `find` or `findIndex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let a = ["4", "2"];
let b = [{"item": "1"}, {"item": "4"}, {"item": "2"}, {"item": "3"}];
const trueValues = new Set(a);
let c = b.map(obj => ({"item": trueValues.has(obj["item"])}));
```

This results in:

```
[{"item": false}, {"item": true}, {"item": true}, {"item": false}]
```

IE11 won't support `new Set(item1)`, you will need:

```
const trueValues = new Set()
a.forEach(item => trueValues.add(item))
```

Your code results in

```
[{"item": true}, {"item": true}, {"item": false}, {"item": false}]
```

because you take all the trues and then add all the falses:

```
[...newItem, ...addOtherItems]
```

If you want to map an array into a different array, you should just use map as is

For IE9, you can use some like so:

```
b.map(b_i => ({item: a.some(a_i => a_i === b_i.item)}));
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple code for this is:

```js
const a = ["4", "2"]
const b = [{"item": "1"}, {"item": "4"}, {"item": "2"}, {"item": "3"}]

console .log (
  b .map ( ({item}) => ({ item: a . includes (item) }) )
)
```

If you have a lot of data, this might not perform well, and you might look at a version using a `Set` instead.  But I would only bother if testing demonstrates a performance problem, as this code is straightforward.